# Internet Explorer 11 as a SOCKS5 Proxy Client Resolves Hostnames Locally, not on the Proxy

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, socks-proxy, socks, socks5

Internet Explorer 11 as a SOCKS5 proxy client resolves hostnames locally, not on the proxy.

Is there any way to force Internet Explorer 11 to resolve hostnames on the proxy? I would rather not clutter up my hosts file...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no version of IE that supports SOCKS5 (not even Edge), they are all SOCKS4 which doesn't support server-side DNS resolution.

If you want a SOCKS5 browser, then Firefox does it (but doesn't support authentication).

All in all, given how old SOCKS5 is as a protocol, it's a pretty poor showing.